# makefile conditional recipe not executing

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements, recipe

I have a makefile which produces an executable from several object files and I include a version number in each object file as it is compiled. However, I want the version number to be incremented only when a particular object file is created (ptarget below, the one containing main). I tried to do this using a conditional statement in the recipe:

```
ptarget:=$(addsuffix .obj,$(ouf))

%.obj : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -Fo$@
    $(info $(ptarget))
    $(info $@)
ifeq ($@, $(ptarget))
    perl $(perlDir)versionBump/bump.pl -inc -f $(versionFile)
endif
```

I can see from the info commands that only when ptarget is built that $@ == $(ptarget) -- I also tried using strip command to make sure no hidden whitespace, but the perl command to increment the version is never executed, it starts with a tab.

Just to add, this all works just fine without the conditional but the increment happens multiple times during a build, which is what I am trying to avoid. This [example](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_7.html) suggests it should work but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common misunderstanding about make. `ifeq` is a make statement and is evaluated when make parses the Makefile. What you need is a conditional that gets evaluated when the recipe is executed by the shell, that is a shell `if`:

```
%.obj : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -Fo$@
    $(info $(ptarget))
    $(info $@)
    if [ "$@" = "$(ptarget)" ]; then \
      perl $(perlDir)versionBump/bump.pl -inc -f $(versionFile); \
    fi
```

Do not forget the line continuations (the trailing `\`).

Comment: This works, thanks, but not sure why. The example in the link uses ifeq to send one of two different compiler commands to the shell, so I was thinking in my case the ifeq would send the perl command or not...

Comment: The problem is that when make evaluates this `ifeq` (at parsing time) `$@` has no value yet, so it expands as the empty string. While when the recipe is about to be executed `$@` is known and make substitutes it to the correct value before passing the recipe to the shell, just like it does with `$(ptarget)`.